# How to use static members and singletons in dll's?

Tags: windows, dll, mingw

actually i'm working on a windows (MSYS/MinGW) migration of our Linux project. With Linux everything works fine, but with windows i got trouble with static members and singletons which have to be used over the context of different dlls.

I.e. I've an configuration mapper, which is a singleton build in a config.dll. If i use this dll inside differnd other dll, any dll got it's own instance. Is there a way to share the singleton access between those dlls?

I got also a failure using static members between dlls. If i call a static member of an vector class wich is placed in math.dll from any other dll i got this message during make:

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libbrGraphics.dll
Info: resolving binrev::brMath::brVector3f::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z      by linking to   
__imp___ZN6binrev6brMath10brVector3f15NEGATIVE_UNIT_ZE (auto-import)
```

Knowes anyone a solution?
Best regards,
Chris

Answer (score -1):

A DLL is a library, if you want to share configuration data you will have to map the singleton on a shared memory map or use some other RPC mechanism. You wouldn't expect the error log on someone else's computer to be filled with what you print to stderr would you?